# Perl - Print output to files in a different directory

Tags: perl, file, path, directory, file-io

Good morning!

I am sorry if this has been posted before - I could not find it. I just need a little point into the right direction, this is my homework and I feel it is almost done. What I want to do is take data from files in a different folder from where the script is run, process the data inside Perl, then print the output to another directory. Now I got the two parts done, but what I fail with is that Perl does not find the path to where I want to save the files. It just sais "No file or directory with that names exists", but it does! Here is the part of the script for that:

```
my @files = <$ENV{HOME}/Docs/unprocessed/*.txt>;
my $path = "$ENV{HOME}/Docs/results";

<looping through @files, processing each file in the unprocessed folder...>

open (OUTFILE, $path . '>$file') or die $!;
print OUTFILE ""; # "" Is really the finished calculations from the loop, not important here.
close FILE;
close OUTFILE;
```

I bet its something stupid...

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

`use File::Basename;` and 

`open (OUTFILE, ">$path/" . basename($file))`

Did the trick.

Comment: There's no needs to put `solved` in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are mixing the "write" token `>` in with the filename.  This:

```
open (OUTFILE, $path . '>$file')
```

Should be:

```
open (OUTFILE, ">$path/$file")
```

You will also likely have to strip the `.../Docs/unprocessed/` prefix from your filename:

```
use File::Basename;

open (OUTFILE, ">$path/" . basename($file))
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a million Howie!

Now my boot has an appointment with a specific Perlmonk...

Comment: Three argument open would be better `open (OUTFILE, '>', "$path/" . basename($file))` to guard against weird things in your variables.

Comment: @RobEarl Besides the three-argument-version of `open` using lexical filehandles would be even better. `open my $fh, '>' , '...' or die 'miserably';`

Comment: Any idea how I can add a string to basename($file)? I'd like to add current date and time to the filename aswell, saved in $date.

Comment: Append it: `"$path/" . basename($file) . "-$date"`

Comment: Thanks, I guessed it out. It also worked with `"$path/" . $date . basename($file)` but I had to add a "_" in the end of the $date string, otherwise it looked quite nasty, so I see the point of the "-" infromt of $date. ;>